# what is the best way to bind ListView (WPF) with same icon for each item

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a list view that is binded to some object I've created.
The binding is working perfect, but I want to add icon to each item in my list.
All the items should have the SAME icon (should be defined prior as "file.ico").
What is the best to implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx), e.g:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>           
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Images/.." Width=".." Height=".." />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

You should use a `ListBox` unless you have a specific reason to use a `ListView`.

Comment: Thanks, is this the simple way for doing it? Is it possible to just put some property in  `<GridViewColumn..` ?

Comment: Yes, you could make the DataTemplate a resource and reuse it across list boxes if you wished